# looping using both arabic numerals and actual numbers

Tags: foreach

Is there an easy way to loop this script in .tex:

```
\immediate\openout\mytest1=test1.tex
\immediate\openout\mytest2=test2.tex
\immediate\openout\mytest3=test3.tex
\immediate\openout\mytest4=test4.tex
\immediate\openout\mytest5=test5.tex
```

I think that a \foreach loop would work best, but I am very inexperienced with how latex sees the variables and appends them to text names.

If someone could give me a jumping off point, that would be very helpful.

@David:  I am trying to use the example you created to loop the following:

```
\newwrite\mytest1
\newwrite\mytest2
\newwrite\mytest3
\newwrite\mytest4
\newwrite\mytest5
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{test1}{%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\mytest1{\the\toks@}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{test2}{%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\mytest2{\the\toks@}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{test3}{%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\mytest3{\the\toks@}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{test4}{%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\mytest4{\the\toks@}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{test5}{%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\mytest5{\the\toks@}}
\makeatother
```

I kept your code in the body of the document, but moved the line \newwrite into a loop in the preamble to mimic the first five lines above.  Then, I used the same language that you used to define the new environment: test1,test2, etc.  Then I used the appended name in the \NewEnviron command.  Ultimately, I would like the code to define a new environment for each count in the loop, then write that text into the new .tex files that we are creating.  However, I am wondering the \NewEnviron is rejecting the name because of an expansion issue.

```
\makeatletter
\count@\z@
\loop
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\count@<6
\expandafter\newwrite\csname mytest\the\count@ \endcsname
\expandafter\newwrite\csname test\the\count@ \endcsname
\NewEnviron{\csname test\the\count@ \endcsname}{%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\csname mytest\the\count@\endcsname{\the\toks@}}
\repeat
```

Comment: Do you really want numbers in macro names? This won’t work by default. You will either use `\csname mytest1\endcsname` (and `\expandafter`s) or make the digits letters, too.

Comment: I wouldn't mind changing it.  If I change it to letters, say A, B, C, D...I wouldn't need to expand anything?  For example, '\immediate\openout\mytestA=testA.tex
\immediate\openout\mytestB=testB.tex
\immediate\openout\mytestC=testC.tex
\immediate\openout\mytestD=testD.tex
\immediate\openout\mytestE=testE.tex' would work better?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The following produces test1.tex .. test5.tex

```
\makeatletter
\count@\z@
\loop
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\count@<6
\expandafter\newwrite\csname mytest\the\count@\endcsname
\immediate\openout\csname mytest\the\count@\endcsname=test\the\count@.tex
\repeat

\stop
```

If you would rather the command names be `\mytestA`... use

```
\expandafter\newwrite\csname mytest\@Alph\count@\endcsname
\immediate\openout\csname mytest\@Alph\count@\endcsname=test\the\count@.tex
```

If you want the filenames to use letters as well use

```
\expandafter\newwrite\csname mytest\@Alph\count@\endcsname
\immediate\openout\csname mytest\@Alph\count@\endcsname=test\@Alph\count@.tex
```

Note that you can not access the control name mytest1 using `\mytest1` You need `\csname mytest1\endcsname`.

Comment: this works well, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The following code creates and opens the files

- `myAlphtestA.tex`
- `myAlphtestB.tex`
- `myAlphtestC.tex`
- `myAlphtestD.tex`
- `myarabictest1.tex`
- `myarabictest2.tex`
- `myarabictest3.tex`
- `myarabictest4.tex`
- `myRomantestI.tex`
- `myRomantestII.tex`
- `myRomantestIII.tex`
- `myRomantestIV.tex`

and the “writes” `\myAlphtestA`, …, `\myRomantestI`, …, `\myarabictest1`, …, where the Arabic ones are only accessible with `\csname myarabictest1\endcsname`.

(One should extend the keys and/or use a package that’s already made for this …)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfkeys}
\newcommand*{\fileset}{\pgfqkeys{/file}}
\makeatletter
\fileset{
    name/.initial=mytest,
    ext/.initial=tex,
    immediate/.code={\csname if#1\endcsname\let\file@immediate@or@not\immediate\else\let\file@immediate@or@not\relax\fi},
    immediate/.default=true,
    func/.code={\expandafter\let\expandafter\file@func\csname @#1\endcsname},
    newwrite/.code={\expandafter\newwrite\csname\pgfkeysvalueof{/file/name}\file@func{#1}\endcsname},
    openout/.code={\file@immediate@or@not\openout\csname\pgfkeysvalueof{/file/name}\file@func{#1}\endcsname=\pgfkeysvalueof{/file/name}\file@func{#1}.\pgfkeysvalueof{/file/ext}\relax},
    %defaults:
    func=Alph,
    immediate
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello World
\fileset{
    name=myAlphtest,
    newwrite/.list={1,...,4},
    openout/.list={1,...,4}
}

\fileset{
    func=arabic,
    name=myarabictest,
    newwrite/.list={1,...,4},
    openout/.list={1,...,4}
}

\fileset{
    func=Roman,
    name=myRomantest,
    newwrite/.list={1,...,4},
    openout/.list={1,...,4}
}
\end{document}
```